# Show that there is a Boolean function equal to 1 on the set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that for $n\to\infty$ there is such a boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$ such that $n^3\le||f||\le2^{n-1}$ and with average complexity $T(f)=\theta(\frac{||f||}{log_2||f||})$.
Help me solve this problem, I don't know where to start. If I come up with something, I'll add it here.

Comment: Could you define average complexity and $\|f\|$ please?

Comment: @paulinho The weight of a Boolean function (that is, $||f||$) is the number of sets of values of input variables for which it takes the value 1.

Comment: Thanks. And average complexity?